# How to run multiple instances of selenium at the same time - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I would like to run multiple instances of selenium at the same time. I'm using APScheduler for scheduling functions to be executed, and each function should use its own selenium instance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into threading.

Answer (score 0):

In Python just create a list of drivers, each can be manipulated independently e.g.

```
from selenium import webdriver
drivers=[]

i=0
while i<3:
    drivers.append(webdriver.Firefox())
    i=i+1
drivers[0].get('https://google.com')
drivers[1].get('https://bing.com')
drivers[2].get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

you can manage each instance independently by referring to the specific driver instance.
If you want to run them asynchronously then run each instance within an async function.